# HTMLunit changing elements on page making them inaccessible

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm using HTMLunit (tried both 2.43.1 and 2.46.0).  I'm having a problem where it appears HTMLunit is actually rendering/changing the HTML during the load.

If I inspect the HTML from within Chrome, the field looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
</div>
```

Pretty easy in that I should be able to select the field by id="password", right?  Well, when I load the page through HTMLunit:

```
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
String foo = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println("======\n" + foo + "\n==========\n");
```

Looking at the output, the field looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" class="placeholder" value="Password"/>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
```

Now, one more thing, this div is only made visible by a click on a JavaScript button.  So to do that, I execute:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.js-login-widget-button")).click();
foo = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println("======\n" + foo + "\n==========\n");
```

Now the field looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <input id="" type="text" placeholder="Password" class="placeholder" value="Password"/>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
```

So, now, I have no id to select the field with.  I could select by name, but that input is invisible, so I get an ElementNotVisibleException.

But my big question is WHY is HTMLunit changing the HTML and breaking me?

Help, please!

Thanks,
David

Comment: Please provide your complete case (URL and java code), so others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The URL isn't publicly available unfortunately.